# Upgrade from .NET 4.0 to .NET 4.7

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have some legacy apps (ASP.NET) that have been targeting the .NET 4 framework, which is out of support. Looking at some articles  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/dotnet-framework, it basically says we don't need to recompile our apps to target the newer version of the framework.

How do I make sure that our apps are running with the latest (.NET 4.7) framework?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's as simple as installing .Net Framework 4.7 on the target machine. You may think about installing the latest 4.8.x version though to include all latest security and bug fixes though.

Comment: .NET Framework is a global installation on a computer - there can only be one version installed. If you upgrade .NET Framework on a given computer, it will then be running on that upgraded version.

Comment: I vaguely remember it just being a command in the web config file.... HOWEVER, with a change like this it's worth checking any NuGet packages or the suchlike that your apps utilise - you'll likely need to update various DLLs, which will require a rebuild.

Comment: There are at most four "branches" of .NET Framework present on a machine (so explicitly excluding .NET Core and .NET 5+) -- 1.0, 1.1, 2.x and 4.x (with 1.x and 2.x being mostly extinct in the wild now; 3.5 apps actually ran on 2.x). Any 4.x update you install is "the" .NET 4 Framework for all applications targeting .NET 4; targeting a lower version through configuration is still possible, but it won't change the actual framework used.

Comment: honestly, updating from 4.0 to 4.7 - while desirable - is merely a sticking plaster at this point; .NET Framework itself is now effectively legacy (sorry, "complete") - with .NET 6 etc now very well established. However, .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET 6 is *not* a "just recompile" change - it *will* require some investment

Comment: Latest .net framework version should be 4.8 instead of 4.7. You would probably first install the 4.8 runtime wherever you want your program to run - it **should** just work, but better test than fail in production. Then you can also re-target your projects to the new framework version, update all (nuget) dependencies and hope it still compiles. If it still compiles, chances are good that it also behaves similar to the previous version - again, better test this.

Comment: For a big project in maintenance phase (not to much new development) I would disagree with @MarcGravell, since .Net 4.8 will be supported for a long time - longer than any .Net 6+ Version currently available. However, for a project that's actively developed, switching to .Net 6 might be an option in some cases.